# Kendo grid editing + non Kendo editor

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, kendo

Всем привет!
Есть Kendo таблица, одно из полей которого - интервал дат.
Для выбора интервала хочу использовать не Kendo компонент, а daterangepicker (http://www.daterangepicker.com/)
Собственно, создание соответствующей колонки в гриде выглядит так:
`c.Bound(vac => vac.DateRange).Title("Date Range").Width("15%").EditorTemplateName("DateRangePicker");`

Код DateRangePicker:

```
@model string

@(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(model=>model))

<script>
    $(function () {
        var start = new moment();
        var end = new moment().add(28, 'day');
        $('#DateRange').daterangepicker({
            "locale": {
                "format": "DD/MM/YYYY",
                "separator": " - ",
                "applyLabel": "Apply",
                "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
                "fromLabel": "From",
                "toLabel": "To",
                "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
                "weekLabel": "W",
                "firstDay": 1
            },
            "showWeekNumbers": true,
            "opens": "center",
            "drops": "down",
            "linkedCalendars": true,
            "autoUpdateInput": true,
            "startDate": start,
            "endDate": end
        });
    });
</script>
```

Проблема в том, что при выборе ячейки появлется текстовое поле и сразу же появляется календарь для выбора интервала. Но как только фокус перемещается на пикер, и пользователь начинает выбирать интервал, текстовое поле пропадает. И, как итог, выбранный интервал дат никуда не сохраняется, в соответствующее поле модели остаётся пустым.

Comment: Попробуйте просто оставить `$('#DateRange').daterangepicker()` проверьте закрывается ли так интуп. Возможно у Вас какое то событие закрывает пикер. У вас установлен кроме этого JqueryUI ?

Comment: @KonstantinOkhotnick попробовала просто daterangepicker. Всё так же закрывается. Jquery UI не установлен.

Comment: в консоль ошибки есть кроме http ошибок? Возможно есть какое то событие которое закрывает календарь.

Comment: Проверить события можно через firefox. Исследовать элемент -> клик по event http://prntscr.com/fsogvq  и получаем список событий на инпуте и где они расположены http://prntscr.com/fsohbc.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был взят с форума Kendo.
Необходимо добавить валидатор на стороне клиента. Примерно вот так:

```
(function ($, kendo) {
            $.extend(true,
                kendo.ui.validator,
                {
                    rules: {
                        daterangevalidation: function (input) {
                            if (input.is("[name=DateRange]")) {
                                if (input.val() === "") {
                                    return false;
                                }
                                var drp = $("#DateRange").data('daterangepicker');
                                if (drp && drp.startDate && drp.endDate
                                    && drp.startDate.toDate().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) !== drp.endDate.toDate().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) && applyWasPressed
                                )
                                    return true;
                                return false;
                            }
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                });
        })(jQuery, kendo);
```

Данный код будет выполняться перед сохранением данных после редактирования ячейки. Если необходимые условия не выполняются, делаем `return false`, что сохраняет ячейку в режиме редактирования.